# Windows Ubuntu Bash SSH into Github

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, github, ssh

I am having trouble using SSH with Window's Ubuntu Bash version 14.04. Here are the steps I took

1. Generated a SSH key and it is in ~/.ssh/id_rsa
2. I added the key in id_rsa.pub to Github
3. I ran ssh-add to add the key to bash

However, when I try to clone a private repository (that I have permissions to use, and can load in my browser) I get an error "Permission Denied (publickey)".

Here is what I have verified/double checked:

1. The key is correct on Github
2. The key is correct locally
3. The filepath is correct
4. My user "Chinnick967" owns the directories so it's not a root ownership problem
5. I have set the permissions to at least 700
6. Bash has the key loaded when I check with ssh-add -l

Anyone have any ideas?

[image: result from running ssh -vT git@github.com]

Comment: Try with more verbose debug log (`-vvv` switches).

Answer (score 0):

You should use git as username. In this case

```
User git
```

That should create the keys, you can check https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/